# Sort data by group and get the max, min and range

Tags: vb.net

I need help to sort the data based on its group column.
I have an example table below using datagridview,

I'm thinking to use array and nested loop to check each rows but I can't figure out how I will start the logic sequence.

Table 1: Raw Data

Table 2: What I want to accomplish.

[image: Table 1-2]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the second table doesn't seem to be sorted on the Group Column :)

Answer (score 0):

I wished you had posted at least some code. 
If you can't sort and group the datasource of the datatable.
Adept the code that is posted here
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40a55e91-46dd-4e45-933e-19425b3eb347/how-to-gruop-by-in-datatable-vbnet?forum=adodotnetdataset

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I have used dummy table to sort manually everything. then clear the table again and again to loop through the table1.